# Creating custom tags and editing IPTC metadata using Commons imaging or Sanselan android

Tags: android, metadata, apache-commons, iptc

I've an image with which I have to add `IPTC` metadata like city,state description and send them to server.

I've searched everywhere and found lots of libraries like `IIMJ4`,`Sanselan` and `Commons Imaging` but there is no working example.
 And the documentation isn't enough to work out.

Can somebody provide me an example how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ICAFE](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) I created from scratch a couple of years ago. To achieve your goal, it is as easy as:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("input.jpg");
FileOutputSteam fout = new FileOutputStream("output.jpg");

Metadata.insertIPTC(fin, fout, createIPTCDataSet(), true);
fin.close();
fout.close();

private static List<IPTCDataSet> createIPTCDataSet() {
        List<IPTCDataSet> iptcs = new ArrayList<IPTCDataSet>();
        iptcs.add(new IPTCDataSet(IPTCApplicationTag.CITY, "My City"));
        iptcs.add(new IPTCDataSet(IPTCApplicationTag.PROVINCE_STATE, "My State"));
        iptcs.add(new IPTCDataSet(IPTCApplicationTag.DOCUMENT_NOTES, "This is a test document to insert IPTC into image"));

        return iptcs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already sorted out the issue long back by putting the values in EXIF INTERFACE User Comments section.I will try your code next time I face something like this